# Turn JavaScript into bookmark or bookmarklet?

Tags: firefox, passwords, bookmarks, javascript, bookmarklet

I have created one script that shows passwords on hover just like Windows 8 on eye click.

I have made this functionality through JavaScript with following code.

```
function text(){this.type="text"}function password(){this.type="password"}function addHandlers(){var e=false;var t=document.evaluate("//input[@type='password']",document,null,6,null);for(var n=t.snapshotLength-1,r;r=t.snapshotItem(n);n--){if(!e){r.addEventListener("mouseover",text,false);r.addEventListener("mouseout",password,false)}else{r.addEventListener("focus",text,false);r.addEventListener("blur",password,false)}}}addHandlers()
```

Sorry for the packed JavaScript code, but I want to create a bookmark or bookmarklet that run thiss script...

I tried:

```
javascript:(mycode);
```

But it didn't work...

Comment: bookmark is not very specific. There is more than one program that knows something like a bookmark/bookmarklet. Of course it seems that you mean a browser. Well there is Firefox, IE, Opera etc.. which one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To solve your specific problem I managed to get your JavaScript code to execute without any error in this version:

```
javascript:(function(){function text(){this.type="text"};function password(){this.type="password"};function addHandlers(){var e=false;var t=document.evaluate("//input[@type='password']",document,null,6,null);for(var n=t.snapshotLength-1,r;r=t.snapshotItem(n);n--){if(!e){r.addEventListener("mouseover",text,false);r.addEventListener("mouseout",password,false)}else{r.addEventListener("focus",text,false);r.addEventListener("blur",password,false)}}};addHandlers();alert("bookmarklet loaded");})();
```

To see if your code works, I added an `alert("bookmarklet loaded");` at the end of the bookmarklet. So you can try and should - since I tested on Firefox 17- see as a result a messagebox appears. If your code works or does not work I am unable to say, but of course this was not the question.

There are some things you can keep in mind or make transformation of JavaScript code within `<script></script>` tags easier to be adopted for a bookmarklet

- In normal JavaScript code a newline can separate two commands. Bookmarklets are in one line so substitute the linebreak with a semicolon **;**.

#### An example here

Let's have an example. Let's have two sourcecode snippets with two instructions:

```
var anumber=1
var atext="hallo"
```

When put all in one line (= make the linebreak to whitespaces) you would first end up with this:

```
var anumber=1 var atext="hallo"
```

This is not valid JavaScript code anymore. If you want to combine two instructions in one line you need to separate/delimit the two instructions by using a semicolon like this:

```
var anumber=1; var atext="hallo"
```

- Wrap all you code in kind of this kind of closure:
  `javascript:(function(){ [...here your code...] })();`

There are quite some websites out there to investigate the solution. Like [here](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application/).

Comment: In normal javascript code a newline can seperate two commands. Bookmarklets are in one line so substitute the linebreak with a semicolon ; what does it mean.. can u elaborate more??

Comment: I recommend inserting semicolons always, although you can read more about it [here](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons).

Answer (score 8):

You were actually quite close. You just need to put it this way:

```
javascript:(function(){mycode})();
```

In your example, you can try this:

```
javascript:(function(){function text(){this.type="text"};function password(){this.type="password"};function addHandlers(){var e=false;var t=document.evaluate("//input[@type='password']",document,null,6,null);for(var n=t.snapshotLength-1,r;r=t.snapshotItem(n);n--){if(!e){r.addEventListener("mouseover",text,false);r.addEventListener("mouseout",password,false)}else{r.addEventListener("focus",text,false);r.addEventListener("blur",password,false)}}};addHandlers()})();
```

Please pay attention to semicolons when you minify your code, you were missing some of them.

Comment: P.S. After posting my answer I tried your code, and I like it! Useful trick, I saved this bookmarklet